# How do I get more details on my request error on IIS7

Tags: rest, iis-7, configuration

I have deployed a REST service on an external server (IIS7). When I start the service from VS on the Dev server it works fine. But on the server i get:

`Request Error, The server encountered an error processing the request. Please see the service help page for constructing valid requests to the service.`

How do I get more details on this error? I have looked in the log files directory that is configured under Logging feature for this web site in IIS Manager, but there are no files at all for this site it seems.

Answer (score 2):

You should look in the Windows Event Log using the [Event Viewer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Open-Event-Viewer) application (eventvwr.exe). Output to the IIS log files may be buffered so their contents may be updated after a restart, or when IIS is set to do it. Restarting IIS is a surefire way to force this.

Comment: Thanks, do you know more precisely where in the eventviewer to find the information. I have browsed around a while around the many different levels and log nodes, I can't find any errors from my REST service.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [blog post](http://nsamteladze.blogspot.com/2013/07/enable-verbosely-errors-in-wcf-data.html) on how to do this.

I'm aware of 3 ways to get nicer errors:

1. Set `UseVerboseErrors` in `InitializeService` method. However, this won't give you anything if your error occurs before `InitializeService` is called (which happens).
2. Set `IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults` to true using an attribute before your service class.
3. Set `IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults` to true using web.config.

Comment: class attribute: [System.ServiceModel.ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]